# How to enable microphone in html page

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, voice-recognition

I am creating a website that has a textbox where the user can input text by saying it... In the input tag I am using `x-webkit-speech`.
However the microphone icon that I want it does not appear!

That's the jQuery code I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function() { $("#voiceapi").bind('webkitspeechchange', function(e) {
    var val = $(this).val();

    if(val == "open face book") {window.location.replace("http://fb.com");      }
});});
```

By the way, I am creating this page for a chrome extension, although google chrome supports voice recognition, it still does not work!

Answer (score 3):

Support for the `x-webkit-speech` attribute has been removed in Chrome v36 due to a [security vulnerability that allowed malicious sites to snoop on anything you say](https://blogs.janestreet.com/disabling-chromes-x-webkit-speech-vulnerability/).

Instead you are supposed to use the Javascript API: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API